# flickering logs screen

Tags: upgrade, updates

Every time when I start my laptop I see very much logs on my screen: https://vimeo.com/358469347 After 10 minutes my laptop starts and I can work on this.

This came after the update: `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

Installed third-party apps on laptop: qbittorrent, plex media server, webmin, tor browser.

Ubuntu version is 19.04

A few photos with logs on flickering screen: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x7bn079ejszi02b/AABo2BM_Nyqa8OrrdZwOhwS-a?dl=0